# Blocking scroll in a popin modal

Tags: javascript, scroll, modal-dialog

I am working on a CMP implementation.
On mobile, I have some issues because when users scrolls in part of the popin/modal, it triggers the scroll on the page behind the popin.

Any tips about how to block the scroll behind?
I looked into https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock#readme but or it didnt work, or I didnt implement it correctly and need to check it further

Thanks !

Comment: You could add a class to the `body` when the modal opens with `overflow: hidden` and remove the class when the modal closes.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is add `overflow: hidden` to the `body`/content element when the modal is open.

```css
body.contains-open-modal {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then add `contains-open-modal` class to `body` when you open the Modal.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesnt seem to work. Yesterday I had a solution : putting the #main and #footer in display:none, but that doesnt seem a really good idea for seo reasons...